# is there A Communication Manager for vue components?

Tags: express, vue.js

I was Vue.js now for a project and created and used a lot of components. 
Now I started to have the problem  of having too many eventemitters and props that I need to keep track of.

I guess to illustrate the problem  the best I will use an example:

Lets say you have a main.vue and 2 or 3 Components. 
One contains a button that should manipulate the other 2 components or switch them out.

Now I need to emit an event to the main.vue and then main.vue has to change a binded variable and pass props down to the other 2 components. 
Alright: Now lets put the button in a component of of a component. You need to make sure that every link between a parent and a child is correct.

Now create a bit project and put a button in another components and you have to change everything.

So is there a good way to avoid this? 
Something like a broadcast function so that every component is receiving the event?
Or a Manager that is handling the communication of all components?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: For those down-voting the question, can you provide some feedback as to why?

Comment: @Daniel I didn't downvote, but the scope of this question is overly broad, prone to opinion (I think Vuex is a vast overkill in most cases for example), and covered directly in the documentation.

Comment: I agree (almost) 100%. I find sometimes people make presumption about how to solve a problem, without knowing about alternatives, or how to ask the question properly. The question is vague, but rather then RTFM-ing the OP, providing perspective may be more helpful.

Comment: Well, Im new to vue.js and I tried to explain a problem that is on the one side difficult to discribe and on the other not trivial to solve. I found a lot questions about easier topics, which also could have been found in documentations etc. @Daniel: Thats absolutely normal. Coding is about finding out how to do it. If you dont know it, you need to solve it yourselve. I added my solution ideas to help you to know what I want to achieve.

Comment: I agree its not the best question I ever asked but tell me how I should have made it different? Also, about the opinion: I didnt want to research the names of all the paradigms this problem would brake. (e.g. tight coupling)

Comment: I"m not sure how much more I can offer. __Vuex__ would likely be the choice most would use to solve this, but you need to invest some time to learn how to use it. I could post resources, but they're easy enough to google.

Answer (score 2):

use a flux pattern ([vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/))

At first you may think that this does not really answer the question, since it deals with storage of data, and not handling of events. The flux pattern changes the architecture of your application by creating a single store (think database) that all components can read and write from. Coupled with the reactive nature of the reactive frameworks such as vue (or react), the components will react to a change in data. So instead of tightly coupling component `A` to `D` through `B` and `C`, you'd have component `A` listen to mutations in object `X`, and component `D` makes changes to object `X`. When the change happens, component `A` gets updated without having to listen to any of the children's `$emit` functions firing. At first it may seem daunting, but the investment is worthwhile.